# Display JSON data from POST request in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have an `apache2` server and `php` file to receive `json` via `POST` in my `php code` like this

```php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$mac_ = $json["code"];
$userId_ = $json["msg"];
```

and saving it to `mysql`. This work when I send post via `python's requests` but not when I'm recieving data from `API android device`. - When I look at the apache log file, there is a connection, so I'm assuming that some data are received, but because I can't touch that `API android device` I'm not sure if this part `$json["code"]` has a right parameter. I would like to know a way to save somewhere all recieved data from this part

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

because I can't check it by `echo` or so

Comment: hi, perhaps send it to a file with `file_put_contents('/tmp/some/file', var_export($json, true));`

Comment: hi, thanks for the hint! I'm added this part to my code
`file_put_contents('/tmp/data2.txt', var_export($json, true));` but nothing save(not even the file), should I assume the variable is empty?

Comment: I found it in `/tmp/systemd-private.../tmp/data2.txt` but it contains `NULL`, so empty variable?

Comment: NULL most likely means that decoding the JSON failed. So log what json_last_error/json_last_error_msg have to say as well - and the original input data.